# How can I resolve circular dependencies in Ant destructive changes

Tags: deployment, ant

Trying to change a field type, that fieldtype is referenced by a page, which is referenced by a weblink, which is referenced on a layout.  I'm attemptiong a destructiveChangesPre.xml to take them out and re-deploy them, but I'm hitting a wall with this

`[sf:deploy] 1.  layouts/c-APAC ETF%2FFoETF.layout (Agreement__c-APAC ETF%2FFoETF) -- Error: Cannot delete the only layout [sf:deploy] 2.  objects/Agreement__c.object (Agreement__c.Fund_Detail_Report) -- Error: This WebLink is referenced elsewhere in salesforce.com - Agreement__c-APAC ETF%2FFoETF.`

How can I get round this to remove the downstream dependencies?

Comment: To change a fieldtype from text to picklist, I need to remove references to it first, then redeploy them.  Those references themselves have refernces.  SO I need to work up the chain, removing things until it lets me delete and recreate the field, then redeploy all those dependencies.  One of the dependencies in this chain is the weblink that is sitting on three page layouts, which it won't let me remove if it's the only layout.  I think the workaround will be deploy a version of the layout without the link, then run the deployment that does the dependency management and reinstates it.

Comment: Oh I know the dependencies - removing them is the issue here ;-)